# Android extract multiple tables from website

Tags: android, html, web-scraping, html-table

After a couple weeks of being stuck I was able to login to a website automatically and able to download an Excel file and also able to view the website body.

I have another issue and hope you can help. How can I extract every table? The data of every table will be inserted to a sqllite database. The following is an example of the table from the website:

```
<tr class="odd">
                <td colspan="10" style="text-align:center;font- 
 size:12px;font-weight:600;">
                    122 Address
                </td>
            </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td>122Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name/td>
            <td>Aug 06 -- Sep 07</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
09-19 17:11:36.396 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp 
I/System.out:           <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="9">Remarks</td>
            </tr>



            <tr class="even">
                <td colspan="10" style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;font-weight:600;">
                    154 Address
                </td>
            </tr>

        <tr class="even">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Aug 30 -- Sep 02</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
09-19 17:11:36.397 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp I/System.out:             <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="odd">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 07 -- Sep 09</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="even">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 14 -- Sep 16</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
09-19 17:11:36.398 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp 
I/System.out:           <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="odd">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 16 -- Sep 19</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td><div style="color:red;font-weight:600;">PH</div></td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
09-19 17:11:36.399 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp 
I/System.out:           <td>Agent Name/td>
        </tr>

            <tr class="odd">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="9">Remarks</td>
            </tr>


        <tr class="even">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 20 -- Sep 23</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td><div style="color:red;font-weight:600;">PH</div></td>
            <td>No</td>
09-19 17:11:36.400 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp 
I/System.out:           <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="odd">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 28 -- Sep 30</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>

09-19 17:11:36.401 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp 
I/System.out:       
        <tr class="even">
            <td>154Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 30 -- Oct 06</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td><div style="color:red;font-weight:600;">PH</div></td>
            <td><div style="color:red;font-weight:600;">GR</div></td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>



09-19 17:11:36.402 14017-14017/com.pmapp.mikeys.propertymanagementapp 
I/System.out:           <tr class="odd">
                <td colspan="10" style="text-align:center;font- 
size:12px;font-weight:600;">
                    165 Street address
                </td>
            </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td>165Address</td>
            <td>Guest Name</td>
            <td>Sep 01 -- Sep 03</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Agent Name</td>
        </tr>
```

I hope you  can help. So I will make a variable of each items such as:

```
Address,
Guest Name,
Check In, 
Check Out,
Early Arrival,
Late Departure,
Pool Heat,
Grill,
Crib,
High Chair,
Agent,
Remarks (if any)
```

Comment: OK I was able to extract the the tds but how do I only get the value that is inside the <td>VALUE</td> ??

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSoup](https://jsoup.org) and follow their documentation to get the tables from DOM. Add `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'` in you dependency

Comment: Im using Httpclient to login to the website. If i use jsoup i dont think i would be logged in. Ive tried using jsoup to login but my code did not work but when I used the httpclient i was able to login automatically

Comment: After you login you get back a table in html format right?

Comment: thats correct and part of the table in html format is in the code i posted above.

Comment: So you can use jsoup to parse only that. Httpclient creates the connection and gets the response. Use jsoup to only parse that response.

Comment: OK I was able to extract the the tds but how do I only get the value that is inside the <td>VALUE</td>

Comment: You probably got the <td> as a Element object, lets say Element tableData. Call tableData.text() method to get the VALUE